Unable to initialize git project on remote Windows Server machine
I have a local development PC and a remote Windows Server machine. Git is installed on both. I already have an Angular project (angular_project_old) with a Git repository, and I am successfully able to pull/push the changes that I do on my local PC to the remote Git server. However, I am facing issues when setting up a new project.
I have created a new Angular project on my development PC called (angular_project_new). In this, I have initialized git repository:
E:\angular_project_new\ > git init
E:\angular_project_new\ > git add .
E:\angular_project_new\ > git commit

Then I created a bare repository by remote-logging on my server (10.1.1.1):
D:\projects\ > git init --bare angular_project_new.git

Then I set the remote origin URL to a URL of the server similar to my old/working angular project.
git remote add origin //10.1.1.1/projects/angular_project_new.git

Now it lists the origin URL correctly but when I try to push the code from my development PC, it returns error.
E:\angular_project_new\ > git push -u origin master
fatal: '10.1.1.1/projects/angular_project_new.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository

I don't understand the reason for this error when an identical remote URL is working for my old project.
E:\angular_project_old\ > git remote -v
origin //10.1.1.1/projects/angular_project_old.git (fetch)
origin //10.1.1.1/projects/angular_project_old.git (push)

This works fine.
However, for my new project:
E:\angular_project_new\ > git remote -v
origin //10.1.1.1/projects/angular_project_new.git (fetch)
origin //10.1.1.1/projects/angular_project_new.git (push)

It does not work! How may I resolve this issue?

did you try \\10.1.1.1 or mounting as a drive?

@DanielA.White Yes, I tried \\10.1.1.1 but it doesn't work either. I'm not sure how I can do the drive mounting.

In windows it’s called mapping a network drive

I found out that the problem was with the sharing of remote repository's folder. I had turned sharing on for the folder but for some reason it did not take effect until I restarted the server. After a restart, it worked as expected.
